# Verbally differentiating between "sign" and "sine"

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics, homophones

I'm teaching math to undergrads. The classes are taught in English, which is a second language for me.

In the middle of one class I've stumbled upon an unexpected problem: the inability to distinguish between "sign" and "sine". Sometimes it's evident from the context. Sometimes not. For example, if I'm saying to student "You forgot a /saɪn/ here", it can both mean "a sine (of x)" or "a (minus) sign".

Is there a way to make a clear distinction between these two homophones in spoken language, or should I just try my best to build unambiguous phrases?

Comment: Sometimes I spell the word immediately after pronouncing it, "sign s-i-g-n." And sometimes I say "trig sine" or "sign positive or negative." I suppose that the immediate purpose would also be served if you pronounced the trig function sin like the crime against G-d, a sin, although that would make you uncool in the math world.

Comment: Why not provide the context (as you do in this question) when speaking to your student. Don't say "you forgot a sign/sine here", say "you forgot a minus sign".

Comment: Pronounce _sine_ like _sin_; i.e, use a lax vowel, not a diphthong. For one thing, it's what nativespeaking math students often do, since it's always _sin x_ and never _sine x_ or _sine (x)_. Likewise, _log x, cos x, cosh x, tan x, cot x,_ are all to be pronounced as one likes, as long as everybody knows there's another pronunciation that English speakers can also use. Think of it as a math accent. Incidentally, _sinh x_  is "sinch x".

Comment: I hear increasing numbers of (scientific) speakers enunciating the /r/ in (metallic) ***iron*** purely because there are more and more contexts where the "standard" pronunciation could be misinterpreted as (electrochemical) ***ion***. But I know of no such "trick" to deal with potential corresponding confusion between (arithmetic operator) ***sign*** and (trig function) ***sine***. If it's a genuine problem in a specific context, all I can suggest is you refer to them as ***[plus or] minus signs*** or ***trig[onometric] sines***.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Er, not in the UK. When I was taught sin, cos and tan, I was taught that sin is always pronounced "sine". I was also taught that sinh is pronounced "shine". These pronunciations have been consistent across different teachers/lecturers at both my secondary school and my university.

Comment: @JohnLawler I"ve never heard the pronunciation "sin" for the trig functino, but I have often heard the pronunciation "sinch" for the hyperbolic sine. So my experience is midway between yours and AndyT's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a math major, my teachers, colleagues, and I nearly always say "algebraic sign" to distinguish from the more likely "sine" in our speech.